# I cannot see the .ics file in mac desktop Calendar. Why? (iCal4j)

Tags: java, calendar, icalendar, ical4j

I've created an `ics` file using the `ical4j` library, and I'm saving the file in the following directory: `Users/[my name]/Library/Calendars/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX.calendar/Events/`

XXXXX... is the calendar which holds some of the `ics` files I create manually using the Calendar application, so I'm thinking this could be an appropriate place to save the `ics` file)

My aim is to get this `ics` file to show in Calendar, but it doesn't, even when I've restarted Calendar. Why is this?

By the way, this is what my `ics` file contains. It seems valid to me:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Ben Fortuna//iCal4j 1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20150326T104947Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE;VALUE=DATE:20150821
SUMMARY:testing
UID:20150326T104948Z-1@fe80:0:0:0:900c:a0ff:feba:f4a1%9
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Any guidance or corrections would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The VALUE=DATE parameter appears twice on your DTSTART property.

Have you tried to import the same event from the client to see whether it accepts it as a valid one ?

I guess even that is not a guarantee that just dropping a file under this location will work. The client may rely on some DB to keep track of the ics files it actually cares about.

Comment: Thanks I've removed the first VALUE=DATE which appears. I've also tried to parse the event but don't think I am doing it properly.

Comment: My aim is to get the ics file to show in Calendar as an event. Does Calendar store events in an external DB? Can one have access to this DB? I thought that removing an ics file within my directory lets say for a Bank Holiday would remove the event in my calendar, but it didn't.